# Adding values in an array (not sum of array values)

Tags: php

I have an array that looks something like this (using json_decode):

```
array [
    0 => {
        "entry": {
            "hours": 0.25,
            "project_id": 1
        }
    1 => {
        "entry": {
            "hours": 0.50,
            "project_id": 1
        }
    2 => {
        "entry": {
            "hours": 0.45,
            "project_id": 2
        }
    3 => {
        "entry": {
            "hours": 0.15,
            "project_id": 2
        }
]
```

There are about 50 entries per array. I want to cycle through the array and end up with data in the following format:

Project 1: 0.75 hours
Project 2: 0.60 hours

I also want to get the cumulative total (1.35 hours) at the end.

I'm doing this with with a foreach and while, creating and updating arrays and then summing them, but it seems very clumsy - is there a better way?

Comment: Show us your existing code.

Comment: Create an associative array whose keys are the project IDs. When you loop over this array, check if there's already an element with that ID. If there is, add to it, otherwise create one.

Comment: Always post your code. I don't understand why foreach and while would be clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

It can be nice and simple if you trust the data to be well formed:

```
$sums=[];
foreach ($input AS $rec)
    @$sums[$rec['entry']['project_id']] += $rec['entry']['hours'];
```

This produces:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  float(0.75)
  [2]=>
  float(0.6)
}
```

And you can get the total with `array_sum($sums)` ... `1.35`

Comment: Using `@` is considered bad practice as it can hide all sorts of problems.

Comment: It is bad practice when misused, but in this case it is simply avoiding unnecessary conditionals. We know the array key might not exist yet, but it's a non-issue because it will be handled properly. Notice that I said this should be used when the data is trusted to have proper structure. Worse case here is ending up with a count for NULL instead of an integer.